# Thresold a color with openCV

Tags: image, opencv, image-segmentation

I need some help. I want to thresold an image with the red colour.
I get this image:
!(http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=652943Slection110.png)

I want to have a great triangle without discontinuity in order to detect corner. (Because like that all the discontinuity is consider like a corner)

I have tried dilate and all theses stuff but without success...

Do you have an idea about how i can improve this result ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Morphological operations seem the way to go.

I would start with a big dilation to connect the parts. Then, find the skeleton or thin the binary image with erosion.

Comment: I did that before but maybe in a wrong way ? What do you mean with "big dilation" ? A big loop when i do lots of dilatation or a big kernel applied to dilatation ?

Comment: Do you have an example ? (Sorry i just begin in OpenCV). Thank you ChronoTrigger!

Comment: I don't, but there is an example in the opencv doc: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html